# LDAP users are not getting listed under WebSphere manage user?

Tags: ldap, websphere, websphere-8, ldap-query

I am doing LDAP with websphere setup. I did all the priamary setps in the DN am using OU=Users, O= O=IN. 
for the federated repository in websphere for PersonAccount i gave the same DN name and in filters i used (objectclass=user). But in the manage user, no user is getting listed.

Comment: This sounds like an infrastructure question not a software development question, you may get better results asking on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on the following trace: com.ibm.ws.wim.*=all.

Restart your server. Go to admin console and click Manage Users.

Look in the logs for "JNDI_CALL search"

You will see the filter being used, eg. (&(objectClass=inetorgperson)(uid=*)) and the baseDn being searched on. Verify these are correct by comparing to your ldif of a user you expect to see or by using the ldapsearch utility. It is probably not correct, so take action to fix the filter.

Comment: Dear Ryan, Thanks for the help. In Global security > Federated repositories > LDAP1 > Federated repositories entity types to LDAP object classes mapping > Group i provided the search bases and in Global security > Federated repositories > Supported entity types > Group for the 'base entry for the default parent' ---- the realm name i provided. Now it is listing properly.